# How are abstract classes instantiated in Java?

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

I was reading *[Head First Java](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-java/0596009208/)* and it mentioned the following:

> The argument to paintComponent() is declared as type Graphics (java.awt.Graphics).
> `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { }`
>
> So the parameter 'g' IS-A Graphics object. Which means it could be a subclass of Graphics (because of polymorphism). And in fact, it is.
>
> **The object refrenced by the 'g' parameter is actually an instance of the Graphics2D class**

Now I wanted to check a few methods of Graphics2D class, so I opened the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) and searched for the class. I found what I wanted, but then I saw that Graphics2D is an abstract class. Now *Head First* mentions that the parameter 'g' is actually an instance of the Graphics2D class. Now I clearly know that we cannot instantiate an abstract class, but we can create a concrete subclass out of it or even an anonymous class.

Now I don't want to shoot in the dark and want some evidence for at least java.awt.Graphics2D.

One possibility I can think of is something like this:

```
public abstract class GFG {
    public abstract void foo();
}

class ABC extends GFG {

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Hey");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GFG obj = new ABC();
        obj.foo();
    }
}
```

How exactly does happen and how are we able to instantiate the class Graphics2D?

I have also seen this piece of code:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
   ...
}
```

Which is only possible if g is an object like:

```
Graphics g = new Graphics2D();
```

Which is again not possible as Graphics2D is an abstract class.

Comment: "Which is only possible if g is an object like-" but it's not necessarily like that: one way would be `Graphics g = new Graphics2D() { /* implementation of abstract methods */ };`.

Comment: You seem to have answered the first half of your question already. It must be a concrete subclass like in your `ABC`, `GFG` example. In regards to the second, your assumption is wrong. It could be `Graphics g = new Graphics2DSubclass();`. A `Graphics2DSubclass` *is* a `Graphics2D`, the same way that a dog *is* an animal.

Comment: "Which is only possible if g is an object like- Graphics g = new Graphics2D();" <- That assumption is wrong. That cast also works if it is an instance of any subclass of Graphics2D (including anonymous classes).

Comment: Ah I didn't see that, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've said in the first half of your question is correct. There must a concrete implementation of `Graphics2D`. You *can't* instantiate it directly as it's abstract.

In regards to your second point, your assumption is wrong. For the call

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
```

`g` must be a concrete subclass of `Graphics2D`, so when `g` was instantiated it would have been something like:

```
Graphics g = new Graphics2DSubclass();
```

The cast is only letting the compiler know that `g` is a `Graphics2D`, the same way that you could say a `Dog` is an `Animal`. There is no guarantee or mention of the specific implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I saw where my approach was wrong :), nice website btw.